# How to pass a huge object from a superclass constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, memory-management

I have a class where the superclass reads a huge object in the constructor (a lot of parsing) to initialize a value from it. In a subclass, I need a second value from that huge object. I don’t want to parse the file twice, and I don’t want to stay the parse result aroud in memory for object life time, because it is no longer needed.

What I would like to do would look like this (**not possible** in Java):

```
public class Superclass {
    private Object foo;

    public Superclass() {
        HugeObject huge = getHugeObject();
        this.foo = huge.getFoo();
        return huge; // “huge” gets garbage collected if not used
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private Object bar;

    public Subclass() {
        HugeObject huge = super();
        this.bar = huge.getBar(); // “huge” gets garbage collected, too
    }
}
```

What I can write, but if `Superclass` is used directly, will not drop `huge`, and it will stay in memory as long as the superclass object is in use:

```
public class Superclass {
    protected HugeObject huge; // to pass the huge object to subclass
    private Object foo;

    public Superclass() {
        this.huge = getHugeObject();
        this.foo = this.huge.getFoo();
        // this.huge = null; // “huge” NOT garbage collected (would cause NPE in Subclass)
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private Object bar;

    public Subclass() {
        this.bar = super.huge.getBar();
        super.huge = null; // “huge” gets garbage collected only when Subclass used
    }
}
```

In fact the problem seems to be counterintuitive to OO programming in general. I can write a `huge = null;` in any method of `Superclass` so the object will be removed *early*, but that doesn’t feel like good style, either. Any idea of a more Java / OO approach to solve this better? Is there something like a “post constructor” that can be executed after all subclasses’ constructors have been run? Something like

```
public Superclass() {
    this.huge = getHugeObject();
    this.foo = this.huge.getFoo();
} finally /* executes after subclass constructor has finished */ {
    this.huge = null;
}
```

Maybe using callbacks?

Comment: The proper way is probably to have a  (singleton or @Component) `Superclass` do the parsing, extract what is really needed and store that (so no huge is kept), then use the extracted values elsewhere

Comment: Your question is an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us what problem you are trying to solve instead of asking for help with the solution, which does not appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: I was looking for the right pattern to handle these, at first sight, contradicting requirements. Actually this is what my program does and I didn’t have a solution (it simply kept `huge` and I increased JVM heap, which isn’t the kind of “solution” I was looking for). Actually, @OldCurmudgeon pointed me to the absolutely correct OO solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use a kind of callback.

```
public class Superclass {
    private Object foo;

    public Superclass() {
        HugeObject huge = getHugeObject();
        gotHugeObject(huge);
    }

    /*
     * NB: Called during construction! Beware of leaking `this` etc.!!!
     */
    protected void gotHugeObject(HugeObject huge) {
        this.foo = huge.getFoo();
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    private Object bar;

    /*
     * NB: Called during construction! Beware of leaking `this` etc.!!!
     */
    @Override
    protected void gotHugeObject(HugeObject huge) {
        super.gotHugeObject(huge);
        this.bar = huge.getBar(); // “huge” gets garbage collected, too

    }
}
```

There are caveats to doing it this way. Primarily, that the object is in the process of construction at this point so there are dangers of leaking `this` which can cause obscure problems.

However, as it is simple and clear what is happening and you can mitigate the problems a little with comments so to me it would be the clearest option.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to re-use it for multiple instances, then probably it is better to pass `HugeObject` to the constructor:

```
public Superclass(HugeObject huge) {
        this.huge = huge;
        this.foo = this.huge.getFoo();
        // this.huge = null; // “huge” NOT garbage collected (would cause NPE in Subclass)
    }
```

Now you are in control of the `HugeObject` lifetime

```
HugeObject huge = /* initiate */;
new SuperClass(huge);
new SubClass(huge);
```